# Is there any way to fill the whole back of this mesh?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, vertices

I'm modeling a shield and got stuck with a problem. I want to fill the whole back of the shield mesh, but can't figure out a solution on doing so. I can't just press F to fill since all of them are individually modeled, but all of the vertices are aligned. I've attached a screenshot bellow

[image]

Comment: Since they all are individually modelled the only solution you are left with if preserving this model is to fill them individually. So select piece by piece and fill the back side preferably with quads. Or you could remodel this and have another way

Answer (score 2):

Hoo boy.
Ok so before I suggest something to solve this at this stage, id like to really reconsider your workflow in modeling: Fill first, extrude later. Also: do not intersect geometry (non-manifold meshes)

For this case i would say that maybe if you used the "Grid Fill" feature you could fill the faces to make sense on automatic (space -> search: "grid fill").
Otherwise theres always the soul-crushing way of doing it by hand: quad by quad (have fun)

At this stage id just trash what you did here, and restart the whole model with the elements already filled and then extrude them. It doesnt look like too much work.

Comment: Thank you. It seems my workflow is not the ideal one. Also can you elaborate more on fill first then extrude later? So if I were to remodel it again, I shouldn't extrude first but rather fill it first. How about when I individually model a part? Let's say the upper part is bigger than the lower, how can I fill it both with only one face? I hope I made sense.

Comment: Just start working with a plane and then subdivide/loop cut as needed to create the shapes, then extrude. If you always start with just the outline, you will get problems with filling it, as the fill just makes one huge N-gon and not quads, which then cant be cut or subdivided properly. In effect you will get a messy topology thats not flexible for further edits.

Comment: I see. I've been doing ctrl+click (add vertices) to make an outline of my desired mesh then just fill and triangulate and/or knife tool to get rid of ngons but it seems its easier to just model from a plane.

Answer (score 1):

You would first have to clean up the geometry to avoid all intersections. If that is done and you have the finished part of the mesh completly manifold, connected and non intersecting you would then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to fill it with triangles

Comment: I guess I'll be starting over since I really want a clean mesh. What would be the best approach if I were to model it from scratch. I use the add vertices (ctrl+click) to make the parts. How can I avoid multiple parts for a cleaner look? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The process to make this work with F (Fill with NGons) or Alt-F (Fill with Tris but this can "detect" holes) will be quite tedious.

I would say remove the extrusion loop and work your way to make it manifold. The fill an then extrude.

Or maybe start from scratch and use your current design as template to trace a new modell the right way.